# How to set up a current page number in jqGrid?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, pager

How to set up a current page number when I am creating a `jqGrid` ?

I tried to add this :

```
$("#grid").trigger("reloadGrid", [{ page: number }]);
```

after this code.

```
$("#grid").jqGrid(...);
```

But it didn't help me.

Comment: is it paging for your gird..?

Comment: @user3588674 - yes, my grid has several pages. And I want to set up some page number, when I'm creating a grid.

Comment: Read this link http://jsfiddle.net/hekai/QEzhr/1/

Comment: which `datatype` you use? Do you load the data from the server using local data? If you fill the grid with local data, then how you do this? (Do you use input `data` parameter or use `addRowData` in the loop or ...). You should include more details...

Comment: local datatype  is used here..

Comment: Thanks, i found the solution -> page: myNumber, . It's very simple. Just add new option "page" in creating gird code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the most scenarios you can just add `page: number` parameter to the grid during creating it (like `page: 2` for example): `$("#grid").jqGrid(..., page: number, ...);`. One can require to reloadthe grid only if one would fill the grid in the wrong way (using `addRowData` in the loop).